# how to use sys.stdin.read() in python

Tags: python, peewee

I,m trying to save multiple texts user enter in a db using peewee module but it give me EOFError  when i press ctrl+d in console.I think problem is whit sys.stdin.read().anyway can anyone help me fix this?
here is the code:

```
#!/user/bin/env python3
from peewee import *

import sys
import datetime
from collections import OrderedDict

db = SqliteDatabase('diary.db')


class Entry(Model):
    content = TextField()
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)  # no ()

    class Meta:
        database = db

def intitalize():
    '''create database and table if not exists'''
    db.connect()
    db.create_tables([Entry], safe=True)

def menu_loop():
    '''show menu'''
    choice = None

    while choice != 'q':
        print("enter 'q' to quit")
        for key, value in menu.items():
            print('{}) {}'.format(key, value.__doc__))
        choice = input('action: ').lower().strip()

        if choice in menu:
            menu[choice]()

def add_entry():
    '''add an entry'''
    print("Enter your entry. press ctrl+d when finished")
    data = sys.stdin.read().strip()

    if data:
        if input('Save Entry?[Yn]').lower()!='n':
            Entry.create(content=data)
            print('saved successfully')

def view_entry():
    '''view entries'''

def delete_entry():
    '''delete an entry'''


menu = OrderedDict([
    ('a', add_entry),
    ('v', view_entry),
])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    intitalize()
    menu_loop()
```

here is error i get in pycharm:

```
enter 'q' to quit
a) add an entry
v) view entries
action: a
Enter your entry. press ctrl+d when finished
some text
and more
^D
Save Entry?[Yn]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Xylose/Desktop/small lab/peewee/venv/dairy.py", line 61, in <module>
    menu_loop()
  File "C:/Users/Xylose/Desktop/small lab/peewee/venv/dairy.py", line 34, in menu_loop
    menu[choice]()
  File "C:/Users/Xylose/Desktop/small lab/peewee/venv/dairy.py", line 42, in add_entry
    if input('Save Entry?[Yn]').lower()!='n':
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in Python the

```
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

there is 2 reason for this error

1.reading the file in the wrong way/format

```
 import sys
 for line in sys.stdin:
     print (line)
```

this how we can read using "sys.stdln"

2.there is another chance for the same error if the file is corrupted

Answer (score 1):

Reading from stdin after Ctrl-D is normally allowed, but I have tested this only on Ubuntu (code similar to yours works perfectly well). I see that this is being run on Windows and the Windows console might behave differently and refuse any read() operations after Ctrl-D. One possible solution is to capture the `EOFError` exception with a try/except statement and close and re-open sys.stdin when the exception occurs. Something like this:

```
# note: check that sys.stdin.isatty() is True!

try:
    # read/input here

except EOFError:

    sys.stdin.close()
    sys.stdin = open("con","r")
    continue # or whatever you need to do to repeat the input cycle
```